# How to write a function in Python that can rotate an image (cImage)

Tags: python

How to write the code? I could only come up with this:

```
def rotateImage90CW(image):
pic = FileImage(image)
oldw = pic.getWidth()
oldh = pic.getHeight()
newIm = EmptyImage(oldw,oldh)
for row in range (oldh):
    for col in range(oldw):
        oldPixel = pic.getPixel(col,row)
        newIm.setPixel(oldw-row,col,oldPixel)
newIm.draw(myWin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PIL/pillow:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(image)
im.rotate(90).show()
```

In your example, oldw-row should be „row”